# YouTube's API playlistItems.list is missing videos

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

`youtube.playlistItems.list` does not return all uploads - some videos are missing. When using search call, it works, but I can't really use it b/c of the cost.

**search.list call**
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCs4br3aZLU0sOEM-3n0-6xQ&order=date&fields=items%2Fsnippet(title)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Pulsar Lost Colony #3 LAVA PLANET"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Polaris Civil War"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Minecraft Mods - Flux Buddies 2.0 #145 STALINADE"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Pulsar Lost Colony #2 FIRST CONTACT"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Minecraft Mods - Blast Off! #83 NETHER PROBLEMS"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**playlistItems.list call**
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUs4br3aZLU0sOEM-3n0-6xQ&fields=items%2Fsnippet(title)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Minecraft Mods - Flux Buddies 2.0 #145 STALINADE"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Pulsar Lost Colony #3 LAVA PLANET"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Pulsar Lost Colony #2 FIRST CONTACT"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Minecraft Mods - Blast Off! #83 NETHER PROBLEMS"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Pulsar Lost Colony #1 The Crew"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**Question**
Notice the "Polaris Civil War" is missing from `playlistItems.list`. I suppose it's not caused by some caching (as some other answers I found suggested), because "Pulsar Lost Colony #3 LAVA PLANET" is more recent, yet listed. How to get exactly same videos as are shown on YouTube pages (when opening channel uploads) without using expensive search call?

EDIT1: I also filled a ticket, but it's been a week without any response. It would seem that big G is not much interested in supporting users of their API :/.

Comment: In search endpoint you are ordering by date. I'm guessing in playlistItem endpoint the default order may be not by date. I'm not sure in what order playlistItem endpoint return

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Yeah, sadly it has no field to force ordering in some way... It might be by upload date (not publish date), but if so, it's kinda useless :-(.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a global issue and can only be fixed if you are connected to the same region that handled the video upload. The order IS by date. You can try making as many reports in the issue tracker and here to get their attention.